# Feature Selection using Maxent classifier

Tags: feature-selection, maxent

I am using [maxent classifier](http://maxent.sourceforge.net/about.html) on a dataset with 138,314 rows and 43 attributes. The form of training data are like below:

```
     Feature             Class
     Cloudy Sad... Humid Outdoor
```

If I test the model on held-out data, the accuracy is just above 70%, I want to improve accuracy by feature selection. My question is, how to perform feature selection using Maxent classifier? Is there other ways to improve accuracy in Maxent model?

Or like **Ratnaparkhi A** paper said:

> We use a very simple feature selection strategy: assume that any feature that occurs less than 5 times is noisy and discard it.(Ratnaparkhi, A. (1998))

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Viliam Simko
Is the Apache Maxent model already has the feature selection function?